# Setting up multiple FTP accounts on domain in Plesk 8.6 CentOS

Tags: centos, ftp, shell

Plesk 8.6 currently does not allow creating more than one FTP account per domain. You can setup 'web users' via the plesk interface but this sandboxes the FTP accounts outside of the web accessible folder (httpdocs). I need to allow multiple FTP users access to the httpdocs folder.

How can I setup multiple FTP accounts per domain via shell that can access httpdocs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). See [What should Server Fault do with questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible through Plesk as you may have guessed, however you can just add normal UNIX accounts on the command using `useradd`, `passwd` etc. [This article](http://www.diademblogs.com/linux/creation-of-additional-ftp-users-for-plesk-linux) also suggests matching the UID with the `-u` option of `useradd`.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked like a champ. Now I need to busy myself making a shell script to automate the process.